# Adding an objectClass providing an entry allready has an attribute and value present

Tags: ldap, ldif

I have created a new auxiliary objectclass with attributes to be used on an existing 389 LDAP catalog. Adding this using ldapmodify for one entry works fine when I specify a specific DN. However I wish to add this objectClass to all existing entries providing it allready has a certain objectClass.

Originally I thought I could do something like this

```
dn: cn=*,ou=bar,dc=baz,dc=tld
changetype: modify
add: objectClass
objectClass: bazinga
```

But this will do it for all entries providing the LDIF format actually support wildcard statements. I have no idea on how to further limit this so that only entries with that certain objectClass is present.

Is my assumption that I can use wildcards correct and how can I further limit this so that only those entries with that objectClass get modified?

Comment: A small note. While waiting for a better solution than mine I am currently working on extracting all dns using ldapsearch -LLL -D "y" -W -b "x" "(&(foo=*)(objectClass=baz))" dn | cut -d " " -f 2 > dns.txt. This will able me to create an ldif file for all users, but I feel this is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not get a response from here I did some more research and found out that the whole point of LDIF is that it is very specific and that wildcards are not or should not be supported resulting in me having to create a blob of lines for each DN that I extracted earlier.

The solution was simply to pull a list of DNs. Iterate over that list and add the objectClass for each line.